# Remove mapbox attribution icon

Tags: python, plotly

I've been trying for hours to dive into the source code of Plotly, but I can't seem to find a way of removing the small icon at the bottom of a choropleth interactive map (icon which is converted to a small text after saving the map to a pdf/jpeg).

As you can see on the image below, I'm trying to remove the small text "**© OpenStreetMap contributors**":
[image: Image generated by the Python code below]

It is because the figure should be inserted in an academic paper, but obviously I acknowledge the fact that this map was created thanks to OSM in a section:

> Finally, we would like to acknowledge that all maps presented in this work were generated using data from OpenStreetMap, an open data platform licensed under the Open Data Commons Open Database License (ODbL) by the OpenStreetMap Foundation (OSMF). We extend our gratitude to the OSMF community for their dedication in maintaining and curating this invaluable resource, which greatly facilitated our study.

Here is a small reproducible example:

```py
import plotly.express as px
import geopandas as gpd

df = px.data.election()
geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(
    px.data.election_geojson()["features"]
).merge(df, on="district").set_index("district")

fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(geo_df,
                           geojson=geo_df.geometry,
                           locations=geo_df.index,
                           color="Joly",
                           center={"lat": 45.5517, "lon": -73.7073},
                           mapbox_style="open-street-map",
                           zoom=8.5)
fig.show()

fig.write_image('image.jpeg'))
```

Looking for your help!

Comment: I think you could instead use mapbox map layers

Answer (score 1):

When you use Copyrighted materials such as Open Licensed Software Media or even Mapping a condition of the Open license is usually attribution in the contents imbedded within your own materials so for every font that is in a PDF the copyright for that font will be imbedded in every single font, not once but individually.

Plotly and Mapbox abide by the conditional copyright of OSM and others by imbed the copyright into each maps contents.
[image]

Said conditions are:

> **Where you use** OpenStreetMap data, you are required to do the following two things:
> **Provide credit to OpenStreetMap by displaying our copyright notice.**
> Make clear that the data is available under the Open Database License.

Their examples for documentation are clear

> In media where links are not possible (e.g. printed works), we suggest you direct your readers to openstreetmap.org (perhaps by expanding 'OpenStreetMap' to this full address) and to opendatacommons.org. In this example, the credit appears in the corner of the map.
> Example of how to attribute OpenStreetMap on a webpage
> [image]